# Rasterio resolution warping via CLI

Tags: rasterio

I'm trying to warp a raster to meet an exact resolution (0.0022500000000000007, -0.0022499999999999977). I've tried using the CLI to no avail.

The example in the docs is

```
 rio warp input.tif output.tif --dst-crs EPSG:4326 --bounds -78 22 -76 24 --res 0.1 -- -0.1
```

Using

```
rio warp Sample2.tif Resolution.tif --res 0.0022500000000000007 -- -0.0022499999999999977 --overwrite
```

gives the error

```
Usage: rio warp [OPTIONS] INPUTS... OUTPUT

Error: Invalid value for "files": Resolution.tif is not a valid input file
```

Moving the overwrite forward

```
rio warp --overwrite Sample2.tif Resolution.tif --res 0.0022500000000000007 -- -0.0022499999999999977
```

does the same, though sometimes it creates a "-0.0022499999999999977" file

Suggestions?

Comment: `rio warp Sample2.tif Resolution.tif --res 0.00225 -- -0.00225 --overwrite`

Also gives

`Error: Invalid value for "files": Resolution.tif is not a valid input file`

Answer (score 2):

The 00000000000007 etc. is due to floating point representation. Just use  0.00225. And because they're the same, your command becomes

```
rio warp Sample2.tif Resolution.tif --res 0.00225
```

Or if Resolution.tif exists:

```
rio warp Sample2.tif Resolution.tif --res 0.00225 --overwrite
```

The examples in the [documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#warp) seem to be out of date. To specify different x & y resolutions, use multiple `--res` args according to the output of `rio warp --help`:

```
  -r, --res FLOAT                 Output dataset resolution in units of
                                  coordinate reference system. Pixels assumed
                                  to be square if this option is used once,
                                  otherwise use: --res pixel_width --res
                                  pixel_height.
```

So the command becomes:

```
rio warp Sample2.tif Resolution.tif --res 0.00225 --res 0.00225 --overwrite
```

And in the uncommon case of a south up raster:

```
rio warp Sample2.tif Resolution.tif --res 0.00225 --res -0.00225 --overwrite
```

Comment: This unfortunately creates creates a file that is kb in size with next to no data in it from a 3.5 mb tif, which is makes no sense as the resolution is supposed to be increased.

Comment: @Hexadecimalism use a positive Y resolution (see edit)

Comment: I was under the impression that more headaches come from that when  using it on a south-up raster.

Comment: @Hexadecimalism South up are uncommon, I've never come across one, but in that case, use a negative Y --res which worked fine with my test data. If you are still having issues, edit your question to include `rio info Sample2.tif --indent 4` output